# Elasticsearch 5.5: Needs help for name search (Higher score for positions)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make an autocompletion, who gives higher score for typed word positions. Sorted by score and then name.

**My goal:**

typing "pet"

result:

```
peter christensen
peter christian grau
peter christian reumert krogsgaard
peter bruun christensen
anders petersen
```

typing "peter chr"

result:

```
peter christensen
peter christian grau
peter christian reumert krogsgaard
peter bruun christensen
```

Above succeed and I was happy, but then something strange happening, when there are duplicates "peter christensen". Now the result looks like this:

```
peter christian grau
peter christian reumert krogsgaard
peter christensen
peter christensen
peter bruun christensen
```

And I want this:

```
peter christensen
peter christensen
peter christian grau
peter christian reumert krogsgaard
peter bruun christensen
```

Please help?

**Settings:**

```
{
    "persons_index": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "persons_index",
                "creation_date": "1499881803116",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "ascii_folding_preserve_original": {
                            "type": "asciifolding",
                            "preserve_original": "true"
                        },
                        "names_synonym_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "aage,åge",
                                "gaard,gård"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "trim",
                                "names_synonym_filter",
                                "ascii_folding_preserve_original"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "LxMHLha-R02i__S7gDWBtA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5050099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
{
    "persons_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "persons_type": {
                "properties": {
                    "fieldDisplayFullName": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                    },
                    "fieldSort": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "analyzer": "keyword",
                        "fielddata": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example doc**

```
{"fieldSort" : "peter christensen", "fieldDisplayFullName" : "Peter Christensen"}
```

**Query:**

_search?pretty=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch

```
{
  "explain": false,
  "size" : 50,
  "sort": [
        "_score",
        {
            "fieldSort": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
              "minimum_should_match":"2",
              "should" : [
                {"match" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "peter" }},
                {"wildcard" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "chr*" }}
              ]
        }
      },
       "should" : [
          {"match_phrase_prefix" : { "fieldSort" : {"query" : "peter chr","boost" : 10}}}
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Peter Christensen (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Christian Engelhardt (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Christian Grau (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Christian Reumert Krogsgaard (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Christian Vagnbo Jørgensen (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Christoffersen (_score: 18.968887)
Peter Bruun Christensen (_score: 1.0512933)
Peter Dits Christensen (_score: 1.0512933)
Peter Fjeldsø Christensen (_score: 1.0512933)
```

With duplicates "Peter Christensen (_score: 14.909464)"

```
Peter Christian Engelhardt (_score: 20.01772)
Peter Christian Grau (_score: 20.01772)
Peter Christian Reumert Krogsgaard (_score: 20.01772)
Peter Christian Vagnbo Jørgensen (_score: 20.01772)
Peter Christoffersen (_score: 20.01772)
Peter Christensen (_score: 14.909464)
Peter Christensen (_score: 14.909464)
Peter Bruun Christensen (_score: 1.04652)
Peter Dits Christensen (_score: 1.04652)
Peter Fjeldsø Christensen (_score: 1.04652)
```

**Diffrent query attemp with no success:**

```
{
  "explain": false,
  "size" : 50,
  "sort": [
        "_score",
        {
            "fieldSort": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
              "minimum_should_match":"2",
              "should" : [
                {"match" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "peter" }},
                {"wildcard" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "chr*" }}
              ]
        }
      },
       "should" : [
            {"span_first" : {
              "match" : {
                  "span_term" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "peter" }
              },
              "end" : 1,
              "boost" : 50.0
            }},
            {"span_first" : {
              "match" : {
                  "span_multi":{
                    "match":{
                        "wildcard" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "chr*" }
                    }
                  }
              },
              "end" : 2,
              "boost" : 50.0
            }}
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on how Elasticsearch [computes relevance scores](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) especially on the [IDF](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) (inverse document frequency).

Therefore, you may try several [approaches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html) to solve this issue by ignoring the IDF. I had a similar issue where I solved the problem by changing the applied [search type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html) to [`dfs_query_then_fetch`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)-queries.

Does your configuration run on more than 1 [shard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html)?

Cheers, Dominik

Comment: Hi Dominik. Thanks for your answer. I have just updated my question with more info. I'm using search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch already. number of shards is 5? I will dig into the links you've have provided me later today and return. Thanks Jesper

Comment: Thanks Dominik for putting me on the right direction. After reading your "approaches" link, it took me 5 min. to solve with "constant_score".

Answer (score 1):

Solved with "constant_score"

```
{
  "explain": false,
  "size" : 50,
  "sort": [
        "_score",
        {
            "fieldSort": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
              "minimum_should_match":"2",
              "should" : [
                {"match" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "peter" }},
                {"wildcard" : { "fieldDisplayFullName" : "chr*" }}
              ]
        }
      },
       "should" : [
            { "constant_score": {
                "boost":   2,
                "query": {"match_phrase_prefix" : { "fieldSort" : {"query" : "peter chr"}}}
            }}
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! Take care, Dominik :)